# Recyclerview with different cursor

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Am using recyclerview with 8 cards and each card have it's own cursor, I have no idea how to render such a view .

For rendering some cards actually I have to iterate through the entire cursor but in other only one iteration is required. Can somebody please help me to render the view

Comment: can you please share some code ?

Comment: I have not implemented the adapter yet, I will give you hint about the view ,.Some cards are listview and others are basic user details like name age profile pic etc

Comment: you need to check this   <arjunu.com/2015/10/android-recyclerview-with-different-cardviews/>